# FlashNode and Drupal : Integrating a flash component on Drupal that persists between pages

Tags: flash, drupal

Does the FlashNode component permits to do that ?
Is there any other component that empower the website to do that ?

Like this website (designed in Drupal) : http://www.ilovetechno.be/ 
We can navigate and its plays the sound well
What component did they used ?

Answer (score 0):

if you look at the urls you can see that all the urls for 'deeper' links to the site all start with a '#'. All links on this  site are loaded using AJAX, without sending a new page request. As far as the browser is concerned a new page is not loaded and that is why the music does not change. I'm not aware of a simple drupal module that will allow this style of site to be built, and don't believe that there is a "quick fix" to get what you are looking for without somewhat extensive development.

There is a JQuery Plugin that does a lot of the heavy lifting: [Ajaxify](http://max.jsrhost.com/ajaxify/)

If there is a module that facilitates building this type of site with drupal I'd love to hear about it.

Answer (score -1):

The company [Cowboys and Indians](http://www.cowboysandindians.be/) in Belgium designed the web site.

Ask them.

Comment: that was snarky and not helpful.

Comment: @mirzu:  *Shrug*  Feel free to share your technique for determining which Drupal plug-ins were used by looking at the HTML source of the web site.

Comment: Post a question and I'd be happy to fill you in on some ideas. You can find a lot! :)